# pie chart label undefined ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, chart.js, angular-chart, ng2-charts

i fill the pie chart data using api i fill the data successfully but label data is undefined

this is my ts file

```
let  arrayLabel =[];
     let arrayData = [];

      for (let index = 0; index < this.responseData.length; index++) {
        // this.asset_category =  this.responseData[index].asset_category;
        // this.asset_value =  this.responseData[index].asset_value;
        // this.asofdate =  this.responseData[index].asofdate;

        arrayLabel.push(this.responseData[index].asset_category);
        arrayData.push( this.responseData[index].asset_value);
      }

      console.log(arrayLabel);
      console.log(arrayData);

      this.pieChartLabels =  [arrayLabel] ;
      this.pieChartData =  [arrayData];
```

this is my html file

```
<div style="display: block" *ngIf='pieChartData'>
    <canvas baseChart  #baseChart
            [data]="pieChartData"
            [labels]="pieChartLabels"
            [chartType]="pieChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
  </div>
```

i also attach the screen shot when i click on pink color than display all the label name.when i click on other part of label display undefined [image]

[image]

Comment: What is data you are getting in console.log(arrayLabel); ?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i get follwing data ["Equity Mutual Funds", "Debt Mutual Funds", "Equity Shares"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.pieChartLabels =  arrayLabel;
```

...instead of:

```
this.pieChartLabels =  [arrayLabel] ;
```